# Query error "syntax error in INSERT into"

Tags: vb.net

It seems that I always have the error `"syntax error in INSERT into"`. Can you tell me why?

```
Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Bro_Proj.accdb"
conn.Open()
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Order(Stud_ID, BookName, Quantity, sale, DateOfOrder, TimeOfOrder)  VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & ComboBox3.Text & "', '" & NumericUpDown1.Value & "','" & TextBox10.Text & "',' " & TextBox8.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "') ;"
Dim sqlc As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
sqlc.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

Comment: Do you have any apostrophes in your textbox text?  If you do then that would cause you problems unless you replace them two apostrophes e.g. it's would then become it''s

Comment: Also, why are you inserting the numeric value with apostrophes: `'" & NumericUpDown1.Value & "'`? And you shouldn't inject user input directly to the query. This is bad from a security perspective (SQL injection) as well as prone to errors (quotes in the user input, the decimal seperator is dependent on your local culture (so it might be '.' or ','), etc.).

Answer (score -1):

The Quantity Data type is Integer so you must remove the simple quote in the qyantity argument, the true code will be as below:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Order(Stud_ID, BookName, Quantity, sale, DateOfOrder, TimeOfOrder)  
VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & ComboBox3.Text & "', " & NumericUpDown1.Value & ",'" & TextBox10.Text & "',' " & TextBox8.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "')"
```